# Removable Images in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I'm writing a ASP.NET program that inserts PNG images into a PDF. Ideally, I'd like to give users the option to undo this action later on.

I'm currently using the [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) library to add the images, which is working fine, but I can't find anyway to then remove them. I've looked into the annotation functionality a little bit, but as far as I can tell there's no way to use custom images.

Does anyone have any experience or insight into this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF format is final presentation format not really designed for this kind of modifications, it is possible to do this with other libraries, but for your particular case I would recommend instead keeping a copy of the original file rather than trying to revert this kind of modifications.

Comment: Dear downvoter, it would be very interesting to know what you did not like about my answer. I am sure other readers could benefit from it.